# PDF Generation Code Library

Tags: library, javascript, pdf-generation

I am looking for a good (preferably free) programmatic PDF generation library but having a hard time finding what I want. Here's what I'm looking for:

1. The ability to do dynamic layouts (not have to specify the x,y of every element)
2. Support Acroforms or XFA so generated forms can be filled out
3. A JavaScript library that can run in a browser

I have found:

- [PDFMake](https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake)/[PDFKit](https://github.com/foliojs/pdfkit) (meets requirements 1 and 3 but not 2)
- [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF) (meets requirements 2 and 3 but not 1)
- [iText](https://itextpdf.com) (meets requirements 1 and 2 but not 3)
- [PDFtk](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-server/) (doesn't appear to generate PDFs from templates)
- [Adobe SDKs](https://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/library.html) (meets requirements 1 and 2 but not 3)

Is there anything out there that I am missing?